# AuthenticationError with Microsoft Graph search/query with some accounts - but calendarView always works

Tags: search, scope, microsoft-graph-api, account

When doing a Microsoft Graph /search/query POST such as:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "event"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "MySearchedText"
            },
            "from": 0,
            "size": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

The result is fine when I use a personal Microsoft 365 account. But when I use another Microsoft 365 account created by specifying a Yahoo address, it fails, even though I have authorized the `calendars.readwrite`, `user.read` and `mailboxsettings.read` permissions (just like I did with the personal MS account):

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationError",
        "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-02-14T18:01:59",
            "request-id": "c064b190-a39a-4e77-bdc2-fa3d25ebdb90",
            "client-request-id": "f78443a1-1d27-c865-567b-9af9beb78933"
        }
    }
}
```

However a `/me/calendarview` query works perfectly (`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2020-02-14T16:33:35.452Z&enddatetime=2024-02-21T16:33:35.452Z`).

Do you know if the `search/query` API requires some specific properties for the user account?

Many thanks for your help, I have spent 1.5 days reading docs, other SO posts, trying various approaches, but nothing helps!

Comment: Calendarview works for both work account and personal account, please see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) but search query doesn't work with personal accoujts. See this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions)

Comment: Many thanks Shiva. Actually I have a slight doubt about the "Not supported" mention for permissions in the second document (the one about search/query): does it mean that search/query is not supported for these accounts, or just that permissions are not supported (and then search/query could still work for these accounts, without requiring any permissions)? It looks like what I experience shows that it's the first answer, but I would love to be wrong.

Comment: I have answered it in the answer box, let me know if you need any more clarification :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendarview works for both work account and personal account, please see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) but search query doesn't work with personal accounts. See this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions).

[image]

The permissions here specify that you need to have atleast the least privileged permission to get the results if you login with the work or school accounts. And the second thing here is there are no permissions that support personal accounts. That means you cannot make this API call when you login with the personal account. Application - Not Supported means that the App context token doesn't support this call.